# Why does Line-clamp is not working on tag button?

Tags: html, css

I have an issue when trying to apply a line clamp on a button element :

```
<button style="overflow: hidden; display: -webkit-box; -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
 -webkit-line-clamp: 1">
        long text inside my button
 </button>
```

However, it works when applying it to a span inside my button :

```
<button>
   <span style="overflow: hidden; display: -webkit-box; -webkit-box-orient: vertical; - 
    webkit-line-clamp: 1">
        long text inside my span
   </span>
</button>
```

Is there a reason why it's not working on button elements (user-agent stylesheet for example) ?

Note that I don't want to use span inside all my buttons so they can fit one line only. For what I tested, it works on every other html tags (a, p, ...)

Answer (score 1):

I would hazard a guess that it's due to the design of `-webkit-line-clamp`, as per the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-line-clamp)

> The `-webkit-line-clamp` CSS property allows limiting of the contents of a block to the specified number of lines.

I belive it won't apply to the first `button` because the text doesn't appear as a "block" ([see definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Block#:%7E:text=A%20block%20on,the%20rendered%20output)), but a span does as is therefore clamped as the CSS specifies

```html
<button style="overflow: hidden; display: -webkit-box; -webkit-box-orient: vertical; -webkit-line-clamp: 1;">
        long text inside my button
 </button>

<button>
   <span style="overflow: hidden; display: -webkit-box; -webkit-box-orient: vertical; -webkit-line-clamp: 1;">
        long text inside my span
   </span>
</button>
<br />
<button>
   <div style="overflow: hidden; display: -webkit-box; -webkit-box-orient: vertical; -webkit-line-clamp: 1;">
        long text inside my div
   </div>
</button>

<br />
<button>
   <code style="overflow: hidden; display: -webkit-box; -webkit-box-orient: vertical; -webkit-line-clamp: 1;">
        long text inside my code
   </code>
</button>
```

EDIT:
I think the nuance comes into play based off [the following](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Inline-level_content#:%7E:text=If%20the%20%3Cspan%3E%20is%20spread%20across%20two%20lines%2C%20two%20line%20boxes%20are%20generated.)

> If the `<span>` is spread across two lines, two line boxes are generated.

Which is possibly where the fact that a `span` is [inline-level content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Inline-level_content) is then semi-ignored for the purpose of the render. I think a button simply grows and doesn't create "two line boxes" as `span` does.

I also added the same test for `div` and `code`:

- `div` behaves this way as it's a block-level element
- `code` acts the same as `span` as it adheres to the same principle